# How to update Entity Data Model?

Tags: database, entity-framework, ado.net, datamodel

I have Entity Data Model using ADO.NET Entity Data Model (using auto generate from database)

I have since updated the database schema.

How do I update the Entity Data Model, i.e. redo the auto generate from database step?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the designer, click "Update model from database".

Comment: Awesome. You would think it would be an option when you right click the .edmx in solution explorer.